# Exporting locust metrics to prometheus when running headless

Tags: prometheus, locust

I would like to export metrics from locust to prometheus while running locust headless. I found this exporter:

```
containersol/locust_exporter
```

and it works fine when I start locust with its flask gui. The exporter is reading the data from /stats/requests on the default port 8089. However, when I run locust headless, there is nothing running on that port, and so the data is not available to the exporter. I can send the aggregate or atomic data to csv files, but is there a good way to get the data directly into prometheus while running locust headless? I would like to avoid writing a large amount of data to csv files and then reading it to get it into prometheus.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you might have two main choices.

1. Don't run Locust headless and let `containersol/locust_exporter` do its thing. How you do this depends on exactly what you need. You can control your load test in a number of ways even when not using the Locust web UI. You can make `POST` requests to Locust web server endpoints, you can [create a load shape](https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/generating-custom-load-shape.html), or otherwise telling Locust in code to change user count and spawn rate.
2. Push your stats to Prometheus directly from inside Locust instead of pulling them from outside of Locust. You can write your own functions to push data to Prometheus using [Events](https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/api.html#events) (most likely either on `worker_report` or your own greenlet spawned on `init` that sleeps between reports), or you can use [locust-plugins](https://github.com/SvenskaSpel/locust-plugins/) can check if one of those Listeners can be used directly or as inspiration on how to make your own.

Answer (score 0):

Use --autostart instead of --headless to keep the UI/endpoints available.

For ex:

```
locust -f locustfile.py --config=locust.conf --autostart
```